# Extfiltrating Google Location History from Timeline

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-latitude

### Note, due to changes to Google's "Timeline" [this previous answer no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290525/wget-your-google-location-history-daily).

---

Google offers a ["Timeline" service](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline) which allows users to access their phone's location history.

I want to extract my phone's *current* location.

If I select "today" in Timeline, I can "Export this day to KML"

[image]

This contains the data I need, but I don't know how to get these data programatically. I don't want to have to log in to the website every time I need this information.

The URL it provides is -

`https://doc-0uom0-1q5a8-s-googleusercontent.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gs/[hash1]/[hash2]/1441116000000/takeout-eu/[user id]/[stupidly long hash]&nonce=[hash3]&user=[user id]&hash=[hash4]`

Apart from the Unix timestamp (1441116000000) I don't know how to calculate the parameters for that URL.

The [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/) doesn't list anything.

I'd like to be able to `wget` a URL to collect my data.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 7):

This will give the latest points, I believe:

```
 https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct. From that URL, I get `<Document><name> Location history from 2015-09-01 to 2015-09-01 </name>` but today is 2015-09-02

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either.  My data is identified as being for a single date (in both the name and the description tags) but the points are from two days.  The most recent point has a time stamp of 2015-09-01 @ 17:54 Pacific.  I downloaded the file at 18:19  Pacific Time.  I had been home for a bit.

Comment: Shoot. I just checked again. My timeline on the web has a point at 3:24 Pacific and the last point I can download, using the url I suggested is for around 20 Pacific, yesterday. (I haven't moved very much -- just inside the house.)

Answer (score 4):

According to this question - [Current URL To Download KML Data From Google Location History?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332904/current-url-to-download-kml-data-from-google-location-history) - the URL format is:

> Eg
>     https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2015!2i7!3i1!2m3!1i2015!2i7!3i8
>   gives 7 days.
>
> Highlighting the parts of the date:
>   pb=!1m8!1m3!1i**2015**!2i**7**!3i**8**!2m3!1i**2015**!2i**7**!3i**8**
>
> Note the month is zero based, so one off normal, 0=Jan, 11=Dec

So, in order to get today's date (2015-09-01) the URL needs to be

`https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2015!2i8!3i1!2m3!1i2015!2i8!3i1`

i.e.

pb=!1m8!1m3!1i**YYYY**!2i**MM**!3i**DD**!2m3!1i**YYYY**!2i**MM**!3i**DD**

Where **MM** is a [Javascript style zero-based month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Within the KML, the times are West Coast USA - e.g. `<when>2015-09-01T12:15:37.836-07:00</when>`

So your requests may need to take that into account.

Comment: Hi, I tried with the above link , but only able to get data for 1 day
http://google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2020!2i1!3i4!2m3!1i2020!2i1!3i27

whereas I am trying to fetch data from 2020-02-04 to 2020-02-27

Kindly help!